# How do I see the final HTTP request via Erlang's httpc?

Tags: http, erlang

I've checked out http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html, but all of the Verbose options seem to give different internal state of httpc. Is there a setting or some other mechanism, so that I can see the final (raw) HTTP request as generated by httpc?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the raw output, I would go straight to `tcpdump`. That gets you the true output, and the true reply. If you use Wireshark, it's quite readable and makes decrypting any SSL easy, too.

Comment: Thank you Nathaniel, it's not exactly what I was looking for but it works. Wireshark is great, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I think that raw output logging (at least for some values of raw) is not a common feature of HTTP client libraries in general. Anyway, whenever I get to the point where I'm saying, "but what is it *really* sending?!" I'm already feeling a little distrustful of the library, so capturing the packets keeps me sane. :-)

Comment: True, but at the same thing it seems like such an obvious thing to include. You're about to write something to a socket, wouldn't you first write it to a file for inspecting or testing?